# The original Lord Haw Haw's life in exile (Ireland)

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-two, espionage, republic-of-ireland

I am writing a biography about my great uncle "Capt Tom Smith" who fought in WW1, WW2 and the Spanish Civil War

During recent interviews the name **Norman Baillie Stewart** [(wiki link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Baillie-Stewart) keeps cropping up as a close associate during his time in Ireland.

**Background**

Norman Baillie-Stewart (15 January 1909 – 7 June 1966) was a British army officer known as **The Officer in the Tower** when he was imprisoned in the Tower of London. An active sympathizer of Nazi Germany, he took part in German-produced propaganda broadcasts and is known as one of the people associated with the nickname Lord Haw-Haw.

**Question**

Stewart's biography **"The Officer in the Tower"** shares a lot of detail about his life but very little about his last 16 years exiled in Ireland.  It's probably a long shot to ask this here, but I would really be keen to understand anything about his life in Ireland, or see serious suggestions where I can carry out additional research.

Comment: My understanding is that he was a member of commercial rowing club in Islandbridge, Dublin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because he pretty much laid low and took it easy during that time.

I'd suggest looking over local Irish newspapers and legal documents for the period in question. Much like a geneology researcher would do.

A paying account at ancestory.com might help with that. However, you do have to be careful with that site. They allow user content, but their moderation tools aren't nearly as effective as a SE site's. For example, my mom managed to trace our family ancestory on ancestory.com back to "Thor of Asguard". (I guess my physique must come from my father's side...)

Comment: What do you mean by "legal documents of the period"? I ask because I am aware he was involved in many court cases here in Ireland between 1950 and 1966.  Would legal documents not fall under the Freedom of Information Act?  Maybe you are suggesting like wills and probate (that kind of thing?). Kudos to your mom :-)

Comment: @StephenMyall - Yes, I'm thinking of that kind of stuff. Abstract and title records too. As for how to get them legally, it beats me. I like to think of myself as a bit of a jack-of-all-trades, but I certianly know next to nothing about Irish law. Generally in my country court records involving adults are public documents unless a judge specifically seals them for some reason, and can be gone over at county courthouses.

Answer (score 1):

I knew someone (long dead) who lived near his wife's relatives in Dublin.  It was always said he drank heavily, never worked and after dying in a bar it emerged he had no money.  His children had to be taken out of school and (I think) the family lost everything.  He was generally held to be a con man.  The person I knew always disliked him but only realised his war history after his death when she read David Niven's autobiography "The moon's a balloon". Apparently he had always been very unpleasant and thought himself above the Irish.
Ireland has had a Freedom of Information Act for years now, so O should think information should be available.

Comment: It is not clear how this responds to the question.